# Performance Issue: Google Script for Filtering Rows

Tags: performance, google-apps-script

The following function serves as a filter of table rows (hides rows) based on a specific column filter parameter.
Execution is extremely slow, eventhough the table is 115 records in total.

Any suggestions on making it run faster?
Are there any background functions I can turn off, like in Excel (screen updating, sheet calculation)?

```
function filterOnDate(rowHeader, colFirst, colDate, typeFilter, valueFilter){
  /* Hides rows of table where a date column meets a year or a month criteria. Params:
  rowHeader: row number of table headers.
  colFirst: column number of first table column.
  colDate: column number of filter column (listing dates).
  typeFilter: two possible types: "month", "year". Are we filtering on date's month or year.
  valueFilter: filter value (i.e. month name or year number).
  */

  if (valueFilter===undefined){ return; }

  filterClearFilters(true); //Clear existing filters



 var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var ss = sh.getActiveSheet();
 var tableData = ss.getRange(rowHeader+1, colFirst,ss.getDataRange().getLastRow()-rowHeader, ss.getDataRange().getLastColumn()-colFirst);
 var numRows = tableData.getNumRows();
 var values = tableData.getValues();

 var months = ss.getRange("Months_Table").getValues();

  if (typeFilter=="year") {
    ss.getRange("Members_Filter_Month").clearContent();
  } else {
    ss.getRange("Members_Filter_Year").clearContent();
  } 

 for (var i=0; i <=numRows-1 ; i++){

   var row =values[i];
   var myValue = row[colDate-colFirst]; //Date value of current row in loop, on filtered column

   var bolHideRow = true;
   if (!myValue=='') {
     if (typeFilter="month" && months[myValue.getMonth()]==valueFilter){
       bolHideRow = false;
     }
     if (typeFilter="year" && myValue.getFullYear()==valueFilter){
       bolHideRow = false;
     }
   }
   if (bolHideRow) {
   ss.hideRows(i+rowHeader+1);
   }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is slow because actions like calling hideRows() on a sheet require an API Service call under the hood, which can take up to a couple seconds each time. There isn't anything you can do to speed up the API calls, the best bet is to avoid doing many actions with them in this way whenever possible. Display issues like the Excel ones you mention aren't a factor here.

I See a few options.  First, is there a reason you need to do this with a script? It's something you can do with the built in sheet filtering quite easily.  (See the "Filter" under the "Data" menu).

If it absolutely must be a script for some reason, you want to try and reduce the service calls at much as possible.

If you are hiding more rows than you are showing, you could flip the logic, hide all rows at the beginning, then only show the ones you need.

If several rows in series are frequently hidden together, you could keep track of consecutive rows to be hidden, then hide them in groups rather than hiding them one at a time.

Instead of hiding rows, you could write the rows you are interested in working with to a separate sheet. Using a single function like "setValues()" to write out many values at once is only a single API Service call, so it takes the same amount of time as calling hideRows() on a single row.

Comment: Thanks, Cameron! It is for the end user to easily filter by year or drop-down list of months, on a date column.
I'll take your suggestion to flip the logic - hide all and show valid records only.

Comment: Actually, I'm now thinking of a different solution. I'll store all table in a temporary array, erase all rows, filter into another array in-memory and write only the filtered rows on the screen. Clicking a button to remove filters - I'll switch the arrays flush to the screen... :). But how can I use a global variable as this array, not specific to a function?

Comment: Yes that's a good approach, you can simply define a variable outside any function and it will be globally available for the duration of the script's execution, however you'll need to stash the complete data set somewhere that persists beyond the script execution. I recommend using a hidden sheet.

Comment: Yes, in the meantime I read about the GAS limitations with re. global variables. The PropertyService and scriptDB also come short to my need. A hidden sheet seems to be the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: Updating: I did try the flip logic first (hide all rows and unhide filtered rows), and it runs super fast! I'll stay with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

When only a select number of columns have a filter applied, I was able to improve performance by only removing the filter on columns where on was applied.

```
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); //for testing purpose only
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter !== null) {  // tests if there is a filter applied
    var range = filter.getRange(); // prevents exception in case the filter is not applied to all columns
    var firstColumn = range.getColumn();
    var lastColumn = range.getLastColumn();
    for (var i = firstColumn; i < lastColumn; i++) {
      if (filter.getColumnFilterCriteria(i) !== null) { // only remove filter on column if one exists.
        filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(i); // this is expensive (slow) 
      };
    }
```